# Using processing.js inside a Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, processing.js

I am curious to know if anyone has been successful using processing.js inside a Firefox extension. I am aware of the difficulties of using external libraries inside extensions and the fact that it has to be loaded in a way that will not pollute the global namespace, conflict with other extensions or Firefox itself.

But with those concerns aside, I wonder if there is anything else that should be considered before attempting it (performance, etc).

I am thinking about using it on a new window, in xhtml loaded from the chrome. Any experiences, ideas and suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt right now, but I think it can be done, we just hace to include processing.js file in content folder of our .xpi